# Unable to connect to Google cloud SQL

Tags: java, mysql, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql

I am using Google compute engine, and has authorized my VM instance to Google cloud SQL. I am using this driver `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` to connect to MySQL installed in compute engine VM, but unfortunately getting the following error:

> com.workfor.service.DBConnection : null
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

```
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1137)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readPacket(MysqlIO.java:674)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1086)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2508)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2541)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2323)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:832)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:417)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:344)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
at com.workfor.service.DBConnection.<init>(DBConnection.java:20)
at com.workforwow.controller.FRLoginServlet.processRequest(FRLoginServlet.java:47)
at com.workfor.controller.FRLoginServlet.doPost(FRLoginServlet.java:124)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:769)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1667)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1650)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1650)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1650)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1650)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:583)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:553)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1125)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1059)
at com.google.apphosting.vmruntime.jetty9.VmRuntimeWebAppContext.doScope(VmRuntimeWebAppContext.java:461)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:248)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:610)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:539)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3161)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readPacket(MysqlIO.java:598)
... 53 more
```

Comment: i am using `con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://<cloud-sql-ip>:3306/database","username","password")`

Comment: do i need to enable firewall to open port 3306?is yes, then what is the command to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to interface with the compute engine from a separate computer?

If that is the case, it seems your server isn't receiving the connection from the client.

Check the firewall client and server side, make sure none of your connections are being blocked.

Comment: do i need to enable firewall to open port 3306?

Comment: Yes, how else would your connection be made? Much like you'd have to unlock your front door to leave your house, sure you could go through the back door, just like you could change the port, but than you'd have to unlock the backdoor (or open the changed port).

Comment: i worked on app engine, now i am shifting my app to compute engine, till now i do not find any clear and simple documentation to compute engine. I would be very thankful to you if you could provide me some link to configure the the firewall and let my app connect to the mysql

Comment: i used this command `$ gcloud compute firewall-rules create FIREWALL_RULE --allow tcp:3306` but still not able to connect

Comment: Did you do that on your client too?

Comment: thanks for answering, connecting mysql in GCE is as simple as connecting in local computer. Most of the people who are new to linux platform(like me) face such problems and make other bother(Sorry). Silly mistake was that i did not installed mysql server.